# How to manage versioning with SugarORM

Tags: android, sugarorm

How can I handle versioning with SugarORM?

For Example,

Database version 1 has only model User, but database version 2 has user, post, favorites and so on.

For example with SQLiteOpenHelper I can use the `onCreate()` and `onUpdate()` methods to handle it.

Or I don't have to worried about that?

I was reading the SugarORM doc, but I don't find any info related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need update `meta-data version` in `AndroidManifest` [manifest example](https://github.com/xdtianyu/CallerInfo/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L62)

```
<meta-data
        android:name="VERSION"
        android:value="2"/>
```

If you modified `User`, then you need add a `2.sql` file under `assets/sugar_upgrades` directory.

Please check more details [here](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/migration.html) and [my example](https://github.com/xdtianyu/CallerInfo/tree/master/app/src/main/assets/sugar_upgrades)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It helps me